# mechanize and cookie enable

Tags: python, facebook, cookies, mechanize

i have problem with enable  cookies in mechanize browser
i used this code to login in  facebook  but it redirect me to login page and ask me for enable cookie

```
import mechanize
import Cookie
import cookielib
cookiejar =cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

#browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)')]


browser.open("https://fr-fr.facebook.com/")


browser.click_link
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.form['email']="xxxx"
browser.form['pass']="xxxx"
browser.submit()
print browser.response().read()
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: i want to enable cookie in mechanize browser

Comment: There are some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25085864/3854195

Comment: code didn't solve the problem